# Move archive description under posts

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

My current WP configuration

```
PHP/MySQL version: Don't know
Theme used: KadenceVersion : 1.1.35
Extensions in place: Many
Host name: Hostinger
Site address: https://xn--capmontreconnecte-qtb.com
```

I'd like to ask you for help with a problem I can't solve.
I can't find anything on the net about it...

I'd simply like to move the category descriptions of WordPress articles to the bottom of the articles. Without having to create pages with Elementor.

I would like to have a code similar to:

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 
  'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 ); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 
  'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );
```

to change the location of the item category description.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Note that to see what is your configuration for PHP and MySQL, go to WooCommerce > Status…